# What is Max allowed size of Swap files for new 17.04 installation?

Tags: swap, hibernate, 17.04

I've not yet updated to  ubuntu 17.04 and I wish to do a clean install

before 17.04 my setup was somewhat like this

```
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  14.3G  0 part /
├─sda1   8:1    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0  89.9G  0 part /home
```

Now I'm going to delete the `/Swap` partition in favour of Swap files, These are my following questions regarding that

- Where the swap files stored? in `/root` or in `/home`?
- What can be the max size of swap files? (so that my partition could have that much space)
- Is it in proportion with RAM? or Disk?
- Should I add that 8GB space (deleted `/swap`) to `/root` or to `/home`?
- How do I enable Hibernation in Ubuntu 17.04?

Comment: I've got a similar setup with 12GB of RAM so I reduced my swap to 1GB. The swap area never gets used in my case. I took 20GB for the "/" part as 14.3 could be a bit small.

Comment: @Ilan until now that was working for me,  you don't really even need 14 gb in `/root` if you don't  install a lot of apps.

Comment: I can't argue with something which works. I have Netbeans and a lot of other applications, so for me that size was marginal.

Comment: @Ilan you should probably delete those comments as they are flag(able) as "too chatty"